# Java Regular expression to extract text from square bracket

Tags: java, regex

How can I extract the text with in square brackets if it contains only dot and no other special character?
For example I want to extract "com.package.file" from

```
 "ERR|appLogger|[Manager|Request]RequestFailed[com.package.file]uploading[com.file_upload]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "ERR|appLogger|[Manager|Request]RequestFailed[com.package.file]uploading[com.file]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[([A-Za-z0-9.]+)\\]");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // com.package.file
}
```

Comment: this solved my problem.But I want a modification, Now i am getting the square bracket also.I want to extract the text and not needed the outer square brackets.that means I need "com.package.file" instead of "[com.package.file]"

Comment: @RemyaPoulose: Pull the brackets outside of the capturing group `\\[([A-Za-z0-9.]+)\\]`.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of:

```
^\w+\|\w+\|\[\w+\|\w+\]\w+\[([\w\.]+)\]\w+\[[\w\.\_]+\]$
```

Would allow you to capture that.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\w+\\|\\w+\\|\\[\\w+\\|\\w+\\]\\w+\\[([\\w\\.]+)\\]\\w+\\[[\\w\\.\\_]+\\]$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ERR|appLogger|[Manager|Request]RequestFailed[com.package.file]uploading[com.file_upload]");
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```